# Plotting ROC for support vector machine

Tags: r, svm, roc

I am trying to plot an ROC for svm, following one of the examples https://rpubs.com/JanpuHou/359286, but i keep getting an error on my final line of code: here is the head of my dataset
head(data)

```
growth LogSales Age    LogTA CoAge CoAge2 Reg DigMkt
1     No 15.87283  45 15.32751     8     64   0      1
2    Yes 16.05044  44 15.27176     7     49   0      1
3    Yes 15.36307  32 15.20180     3      9   1      0
4    Yes 15.09644  31 14.97866     2      4   1      0
5    Yes 16.90655  59 16.58810    11    121   1      0
6    Yes 16.45457  58 15.95558    10    100   1      0
```

> My code:

```
split = sample.split(data, SplitRatio = 0.70)
training = subset(data, split==T)
testing = subset(data, split==F)

###Making growth last to allow for variable importnce


###Fitting model
svm_Lin = svm(growth~., data = training,
              kernel = "linear", cost =1, scale = T,
              probability = TRUE)

##Prediction
pred = predict(svm_Lin, testing)
table(predict = pred, truth = testing$growth)
confusionMatrix(table(pred, testing$growth))
###ROC Curve
library(ROCR)
p<- predict(svm_Lin,testing, type="decision")
pr<-prediction(p, testing$growth)
pref <- performance(pr, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(pref)
```

When I run this line: `pr<-prediction(p, testing$growth)` i get the following error message

```
Error: Format of predictions is invalid. It couldn't be coerced to a list.
```

Any help on how to address this, is appreciated.

Comment: Check `?ROCR::prediction` for how inputs should be formatted. Hard to say what's coming out of `predict.svm` here, but it seems it's in the wrong format.

Comment: Thanks, have tried to format and seems I am not winning still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest next approach. The main issue you had is that predictions from svm were of type factor, then `ROCR` functions are not able to compare them. I will include a slight modification for your problem. You have binary data, so you can work with target variable as a factor of two levels. Then, in the part of `ROCR` you have to transform the factor to numeric values. In that way your code will work.

Also, the sampling method from `caTools` package was producing `NA`. So, I added a similar approach using `rsample` package. Here the code.

```
library(ROCR)
library(e1071)
library(rsample)
#Data
data <- structure(list(growth = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"), LogSales = c(15.36307, 
15.36307, 16.05044, 16.45457, 16.90655, 16.05044, 16.05044, 16.45457, 
16.05044, 16.90655, 15.87283, 15.87283, 16.90655, 16.45457, 16.90655, 
16.90655, 16.05044, 16.05044, 15.87283, 15.87283), Age = c(32L, 
32L, 44L, 58L, 59L, 44L, 44L, 58L, 44L, 59L, 45L, 45L, 59L, 58L, 
59L, 59L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L), LogTA = c(15.2018, 15.2018, 15.27176, 
15.95558, 16.5881, 15.27176, 15.27176, 15.95558, 15.27176, 16.5881, 
15.32751, 15.32751, 16.5881, 15.95558, 16.5881, 16.5881, 15.27176, 
15.27176, 15.32751, 15.32751), CoAge = c(3L, 3L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 
7L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L), CoAge2 = c(9L, 9L, 49L, 100L, 121L, 49L, 49L, 100L, 49L, 
121L, 64L, 64L, 121L, 100L, 121L, 121L, 49L, 49L, 64L, 64L), 
    Reg = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DigMkt = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    )), row.names = c("3", "3.1", "2", "6", "5", "2.1", "2.2", 
"6.1", "2.3", "5.1", "1", "1.1", "5.2", "6.2", "5.3", "5.4", 
"2.4", "2.5", "1.2", "1.3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, we format the target variable:

```
#Format objective var to have a factor
data$growth[data$growth=='No']<-0
data$growth[data$growth=='Yes']<-1
data$growth <- factor(data$growth,levels = c(0,1),labels = c(0,1))
```

The splitting method from `rsample`:

```
#Split
split <- initial_split(data, prop = 0.7,
                       strata = 'growth')
#Create training and test set
training <- training(split)
testing <- testing(split)
```

We fit the model:

```
###Fitting model
svm_Lin = svm(growth~., data = training,
              kernel = "linear", cost =1, scale = T,
              probability = TRUE,type="C-classification")
```

We make the predictions on test set:

```
###Predict for ROC Curve
testing$p <- predict(svm_Lin,testing, type="response")
```

Now, we format the output variables and prepare for `ROCR` functions:

As factor start from 1, the number 1 class has values of 2 and the number 0 class has values of 1. You can transform to 0-1 by making it numeric and the substracting 1.

```
#Format variables
testing$growth <- as.numeric(testing$growth)-1
testing$p <- as.numeric(testing$p)-1
```

Finally, we build the ROC curve:

```
#Build ROCR scheme
pr<-prediction(testing$p, testing$growth)
pref <- performance(pr, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(pref)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: And that does the trick, thanks so much. All sorted now

Comment: @hzhou Great ! If you think that this answer was helpful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left sideof this answer :)